# argument list for class template "std::vector" is missing

Tags: c++, string, pointers, vector

I am in need of some help with this program. I am in my first ever programming class and have run into wall trying to getting my program to work. I have included what I have written so far but still it doesn't compile. It is giving the **error:** `argument list for class template "std::vector" is missing`.

**Here is the question:**
When you read a long document, there is a good chance that many words occur multiple times. Instead of storing each word, it may be beneficial to only store unique words, and to represent the document as a vector of pointers to the unique words. Write a program that implements this strategy. Read a word at a time from `cin`. Keep a `vector <char *>` of words. If the new word is not present in this vector, allocate memory, copy the word into it, and append a pointer to the new memory. If the word is already present, then append a pointer to the existing word.

Below is code snippet:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

/* Create a vector of char pointers to hold the individual words. 
   Create a string input to hold the next input through cin. */

int main() {
    vector words;
    string input;

    /* Keep the while loop running using cin as the condition to read an entire document.
       This will end when a document has reached its end. */
    while (cin >> input) {

    /*  For every word read as a string, convert the word into a c-string by allocating 
        a new character array with the proper size and using c_str and strcpy to copy 
        an identical c-string into the memory heap.  */ 
        char* temp = new char[input.length() + 1];
        strcpy(temp, input.c_str());

    /*  Next, check if the word is already in the words array. Use a boolean variable 
        that updates if the word is found. Compare words by using the strcmp function;
        when they are equal, strcmp equals 0. */
        bool already_present = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            if (strcmp(temp, words[i]) == 0) {
                already_present = true;
            }
        }

    /* If the word is already present, delete the allocated memory.
       Otherwise, push the pointer into the words vector.   */  
        if (already_present) {
            delete temp;
        } else  {
            words.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `vector<string> words;`?

Comment: have you done `include <vector>`

Comment: Do you realise what a template is? What book are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code snippet could be helpful:

```
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <string.h>       //  String.h for strcmp()
#include <vector>         //  Vector Header file is added
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <char *> words;     // vector of char *
    string input;

    while (cin >> input) {
        char *temp = new char[input.length() + 1];
        strcpy(temp, input.c_str());

        bool already_present = false;

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
            if (strcmp(temp, words[i]) == 0) {
                already_present = true;
            }
        }

        if (already_present) {
            delete temp;
        } else  {
            words.push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    /*  Print the desired output */
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<words.size(); i++) {
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any doubt, comments most welcome.

**EDIT:** After reading your comments, I came to the conclusion that you use Microsoft Visual Stdio. See, the reason you were getting warning is that `strcpy()` is potentially unsafe because it can lead to buffer overflow if you try to copy a string to a buffer that is not large enough to contain it.

Consider a code snippet for a moment:

```
char foo[10];       /* a buffer able to hold 9 chars (plus the null) */
char bar[] = "A string longer than 9 chars";

strcpy( foo, bar ); /* compiles ok, but VERY BAD because you have a buffer overflow
                       and are corrupting memory.  */
```

`strcpy_s()` is **safer** because you have to explicitly specify the size of the target buffer, so the function will not overflow:

```
strcpy_s( foo, 10, bar ); /* strcpy_s will not write more than 10 characters  */
```

The **limitations** of this `strcpy_s()` is that, it is non-standard and MS specific. Therefore if you write code to use it, your code will not be portable any more.

Comment: used your suggestion but when I compile I now get the error:

Error C4996 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I used your suggestion however I now get the error:

Comment: I guess you are using Microsoft Visual stdio

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Error C4996 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead.

Comment: where would I put in the 2nd code snipped you posted?

Comment: Replace your `strcpy(temp, input.c_str());` with `strcpy_s(temp, input.length() + 1, input.c_str());`

Comment: How would I show what words were actually stored in the vector?

Comment: `for(unsigned int i=0; i<words.size(); i++) {
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }`